# Can Azure notebooks call Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notebooks

I Googled a bit but question remains: Can Azure notebooks call Azure Functions?

Seems Azure Function dont play well with Data Bricks/Notebooks?

I can think of a way to integrate Azure Functions <--> Data Bricks/Notebooks
My Azure Functions can persist calculation result in SQL server for example. Notebooks simply read from it.

I am however unsure if my approach is most appropriate.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data Factory to orchestrate your pipeline; ADF can trigger both Databricks Notebooks as well as Function Apps. You can also pass outputs from the Databricks Notebook into the Function App.